# Is it possible to maximize the window of a Flash Projector?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, projector

I have a presentation built in Flash using AS3 and would like the projector to launch NOT in fullscreen, but as a maximized window.

Is there any way to do this via AS3?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Capabilities class

screenResolutionX : Number
[static] [read-only] Specifies the maximum horizontal resolution of the screen.

screenResolutionY : Number
[static] [read-only] Specifies the maximum vertical resolution of the screen.

ex:

```
 var maxWidth:Number = Capabilities.screenResolutionX;
```

http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Comment: Is there a way to take this information and set the size of the projector window to it?

Comment: this would have to be a Javascript job, but yes it's possible. In Actionscript you would have to use ExternalInterface to call the JS function ,as for the actual JS function, do a quick internet search or ask the JS guru here ;)

Answer (score 0):

IMHO you can't start a browser "maximized" via AS. 
Of course you can "maximize" your SWF but if the browser isn't maximized this won't help. You also can't start it automatically in fullscreen, this require a user input like a mouseclick.